# Como remover beep do windows de aplicação

Tags: delphi, windows

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em Delphi7, em algumas chamadas, o windows emite aquele *beep*, e ta enchendo o &!*(*&@.

Queria saber se tem como **desativar som do windows** da minha aplicação, com alguma chamada de recurso do windows e desativar da aplicação. Não quero desativar o som do sistema operacional, somente da aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isto em sua aplicação

```
//Desabilitar beep
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETBEEP, 0, nil, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado

Comment: Já que deu certo, pode marcsr essa resposta como a resposta que solucionou seu problema! Fico feliz em ajudar

Comment: Ops, vlw por lembrar